# filetabcharacter check not working for checkstyle

Tags: checkstyle

The `FileTabCharacter` check doesn't seem to work for me. Below is my config:

```
<module name="Checker">
..
..
<!-- No TAB characters in the source code -->
<module name="FileTabCharacter">
    <property name="eachLine" value="true" />
    <property name="fileExtensions" value="java,xml" />
</module>
..
..
<module name="TreeWalker">
..
..
</module>
</module>
```

I have XML files - `pom.xml` and checkstyle config xml - which are containing tabs but none of them are flagged as violations.

Some additional info - my plugin config looks like this:

```
<plugin>
    <groupId>org.apache.maven.plugins</groupId>
    <artifactId>maven-checkstyle-plugin</artifactId>
    <version>2.9.1</version>
    <executions>
        <execution>
            <phase>verify</phase>
            <goals>
                <goal>check</goal>
            </goals>
        </execution>
    </executions>
    <configuration>
        <configLocation>checkstyle/kepler-checkstyle-config.xml</configLocation>
        <suppressionsLocation>${project.parent.basedir}${file.separator}checkstyle/kepler-checkstyle-suppressions.xml</suppressionsLocation>
    </configuration>
</plugin>
```

Answer (score 0):

I ran into this problem as well; the problem turned out to be that the default configuration only looks in source code directories, not in top-level directories.  I solved it with the configuration below, which restricts Java code to source code directories, but looks for XML files everywhere, except target directories.

```xml
<configuration>
  <sourceDirectories>${project.basedir}</sourceDirectories>
  <includes>src/main/**/*.java,**/*.xml</includes>
  <excludes>**/target/**</excludes>
</configuration>
```